# Online JavaScript page to convert decimal latitude/longitude to Wikimedia Commons format

Tags: gratis, wikimedia-commons, geography

I often have to take coordinates like `26.6801, 128.0135` and convert them to this template:

```
{{Location|26|40|48.3600|N|128|0|48.6000|E}}
```

... to copy-paste to Wikimedia Commons.

While some online services can convert to `26°40'48.3600", 128°00'48.6000"`, I have found none that converts to this specific format with pipes. It would save a lot of time when editing Wikimedia Commons. Is there such a tool?

Requirements:

- Paste `26.6801, 128.0135` into a field, `{{Location|26|40|48.3600|N|128|0|48.6000|E}}` appears directly.
- Free
- Bonus if open source with code running directly from Github/Gitlab page.